# Usage and colloquial synonym of myopia

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

Is *myopia* a medical term which is only used in medical and professional context? Or can it be used in colloquial conversation? The question also leads to another question: is there any popular and colloquial synonym of myopia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colloquial synonym is *nearsightedness* or *shortsightedness*. Any of the three terms can be used figuratively to mean "not prepared for the future" or "unable to anticipate what will happen". That said, *shortsighted* is by far the most common term to be used **figuratively**, and *nearsighted* is the most common term to be used **literally** when speaking colloquially about the medical condition.

Comment: It is helpful. Nearsighted is what I am looking for, and I also learn about the subtle difference between nearsighted, shortsighted, and myopia. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Is longsightedness proper to figuratively describe someone with vision?

Comment: @Superuser *longsighted* is not a word I've ever heard used, but it is in the dictionary as an antonym to *shortsighted*. The term *farsighted* is very common and refers to people who have a medical condition called *hyperopia* where a person is unable to see things that are directly in front of them. *Farsighted* can also be used figuratively to mean "prudent" like *longsighted*, but it may be less clear what you mean since the literal meaning refers to the **inability** to see close up, not the **ability** to see far.

Comment: Thank you very much! I almost learned the Longsighted in wrong way. Now,I understand that farsighted is more proper!